# How do I see if a parameter stars with an uppercase letter in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I need to make a script that iterates through a list of parameters and checks/counts if the parameter starts with an uppercase letter. I have some starter code but I am stuck and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Your brackets don't match, and there's no operator between `$word` and the regex.

Comment: ...also, all-caps variable names are reserved for variables with meaning to the system or shell; your own variables should have at least one lower-case character. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: BTW, why are you unconditionally exiting with an error?

Comment: I didn't think I was. What that code says is that if there are no parameters passed to it, output an error statement right?

Comment: `exit 1` is an error. `exit 0` would be success. Or you can just leave off that line entirely, and let the interpreter use the exit status of the immediately prior command.

Comment: BTW, what's up with the "EDIT #1"? Copying code from an answer into the question, but modifying it such that it doesn't work... well, I'm not sure what that accomplishes.

Comment: Well I was trying to show what I had after the advice I had received. I knew it didn't work but I also wanted to show the progression I guess.

Comment: It's closer, to be fair. `then ((++COUNT))`, not `then ++COUNT`; C-style math syntax is only valid in a math context, as created with either `let` or `(( ))`.

Comment: Sorry one more question, you've been so helpful as it is but what does the =~ operator do?

Comment: `=~` is the operator in `[[ ]]` to evaluate a regular expression (given on the right-hand side), just as `=` is the operator to evaluate a glob-style pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Several notes:

- You're missing the `=~` operator for a regular expression
- Your `if` is not ended by a `fi`.
- Using `[A-Z]` doesn't work in all locales, and is needlessly fragile. Some collation orders are of the form `AaBbCcDd`, and thus `A-Z` contains `a`, `b`, etc; `[[:upper:]]` is guaranteed to do the right thing everywhere.
- Unquoted `$@` behaves exactly the same as unquoted `$*`. If you want to correctly honor the quoting and escaping used when your function was first called, use `"$@"`, quoted.

Consider instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
(( "$#" )) || { echo "Error: No arguments given" >&2; exit 1; }

re='^[[:upper:]]' # store regex in a variable for compatibility with old bash releases
for word in "$@"; do
  [[ $word =~ $re ]] && ((++count))
done
echo "$count arguments started with upper-case characters"
```

---

Alternately, by using a case statement you can avoid requiring bash, and also check for other types:

```
for word in "$@"; do
  case $word in
    [[:upper:]]*) (( ++upper_count )) ;;
    [[:lower:]]*) (( ++lower_count )) ;;
    [[:digit:]]*) (( ++digit_count )) ;;
  esac
done

echo "Found $upper_count arguments starting with upper-case letters"
echo "Found $lower_count arguments starting with lower-case letters"
echo "Found $digit_count arguments starting with digits"
```

Comment: Something I didn't mention is that I have to leave room for other cases such as if it starts with a number or other. Is there anyway I could form it into a if statement such as above.

Comment: That's an appropriate use for a `case` statement, not an `if`.

Comment: Ok I see, is it just because case statements are more efficient or would it be incorrect to use an if statement?

Comment: you couldn't use just one `if` statement, you'd have to chain a bunch of them (`if/elif/elif/...` style).

Comment: Ok gotcha. Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it! I'll take a crack at it and try it with a case statement instead!

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo Error
    exit 1
fi

COUNT=`echo "$@" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep "^[A-Z]" | wc -l`
echo $COUNT
```

Comment: I'd suggest `printf '%s\n' "$@"` -- that lets you get rid of the `tr ' ' '\n'`, and stops you from having invalid results (ie. double-counting `"Foo Bar"` as two arguments), and also prevents weirdness from `echo` itself (see the POSIX spec for the echo command -- it's allowed to be *very* weird).

Comment: ...mind you, as the OP has indicated in comments that they want to retrieve multiple counts, starting up a pipeline in a subshell for each test is going to be significantly more expensive performance-wise.

Comment: ...and this has the same bug I pointed out to the OP re: incorrectly determining the difference between upper-case and lower-case characters in locales where collation order is the form `AaBbCc`[...].